# How do I sell off the junk in my ship for good?

Tags: starfield

My current home ship was confiscated from some baddies and has some shielded cargo. I have upgraded a bit to increase my cargo capacity to safely store my belongings. However, I like collecting rocks and have stored them all on my ship. These however takes up a lot of mass so every bit counts.

To my annoyance, a lot of the knickknacks in the ship keeps appearing in my ship's inventory and is taking up a minimum of 200+ worth of mass. That's valuable rock storing space! I could sell them at the nearest vendor temporarily but it will come back automatically over time...

How can I get rid of these items for good?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's quite a bit in your question, so let me unpack it one piece at a time.

> a lot of the knickknacks in the ship keeps appearing in my ship's inventory

Whenever you modify your ship (upgrade components, move stuff around, etc.) -- all of the 'stuff' lying around in your ship will be moved to cargo *even if you don't save your changes in the ship builder*. This includes all of the decorative junk items that come with the different components like engineering bays and so on.

> I could sell them at the nearest vendor temporarily but it will come back automatically over time...

This isn't actually true.

As long as you don't modify your ship and add new structural components, the junk items won't "come back over time." Once it's sold, it's sold. Only if you modify the ship to add a new structural component (eg you add a new structural 1x1 store room) will new junk "appear" without any intervention from you.

---

If you get a new ship -- either by buying it or boarding and taking it over -- cargo from the previous ship transfers to the new one. Any loose items inside of your previous ship will be transferred to your new ship's cargo bay.

So if you had decorative junk lying around in the last ship, it will now show up in the cargo bay of your new ship; plus you'll have any decorative junk from the new ship lying around waiting to be transferred to cargo as soon as you open the ship builder.

---

Note that both of these mechanics can exceed your cargo capacity. For example, I have a number of ships. Ship A has a cargo capacity of 300. Ship B has a cargo capacity of 200. When I change my home ship to Ship B, all of my cargo transfers, plus all of the decorative items and other stuff I have lying around loose inside the vessel. Now my cargo bay in Ship B is carrying 375 out of 200 max capacity -- 300 cargo + 75 junk.

---

So, to sell off the junk "for good", you need to:

- modify your ship so that any items lying around are transferred into cargo
- sell everything from the 'misc' category (except the digipicks of course)
- do not modify your ship again

One trick you can use, to make sure all your 'valuables' actually get into cargo regardless of your cargo capacity, is to drop everything on the floor. Pick a room somewhere, and unload your inventory onto the floor ('R' button on PC.) Then, when you get to a planet, talk to the ship services technician and modify your ship -- you don't need to actually make any changes, just trigger the mechanic that moves all of your items into cargo. Now you'll have everything that you dropped on your floor in the cargo, potentially exceeding your storage capacity.

For contraband, you'll obviously want to put that into cargo directly because you'll be caught on a scan if it's just lying around or in your pocket. If you're using the trick to exceed your ship's cargo capacity, this means you'll need to take just enough out of storage to fit your contraband, put the contraband into storage, and then drop the remainder of the stuff on the floor.

(Note that the above mechanics mean that you can't really "decorate" your ship manually by putting stuff in various places, so I wouldn't be surprised if this mechanic changes in a patch of the game at some later time.)

Comment: _potentially exceeding your storage capacity_ - that sounds like a rather major bug... that I would abuse.

Comment: I mean, if you step back and think about it from the perspective of a game designer, it kind of makes sense -- unless you build out some way to keep cargo on each individual ship, it needs to get transferred to your active one. And if your active ship is smaller ... what're you going to do? It can't get auto-sold because that takes agency from the player, and you might be in the middle of space anyway so wouldn't make sense from a story perspective. And per-ship cargo would be abused in a different way by players and potentially be way more problematic. This was probably the easiest solution.

Comment: I haven't made any upgrades to my home ship in a while. Class A ~2000 cargo. But I have been liberating some pirate ships by killing off the crew, taking the ship then switching back to my OG home ship. I guess this is when the junk comes back.

Comment: @JeffMercado Wouldn't that mean less that the junk is "coming back" and more "every time I liberate a pirate ship, I add the pirate ship's junk to my cargo hold"?

Comment: @RavenDreamer I'm not exactly sure which ship the junk comes from. All I know is if I look in my home ship, it is refurnished with the same junk it usually has. I assumed that everything in my cargo is everything I see in the ship as decor. Selling the cargo empties out the ship decor.

Comment: Assuming your 'liberation' of pirate ships involves killing the crew and taking over the ship, that would be how you keep restocking your junk. ;)

Comment: I guess this all happens when you change home ships. I don't know which ship nicknacks become converted first, but I assume your old home ship contents are put into the hold every time you change.

Comment: Part of the issue is that when you modify a ship, it 'defacto' becomes your home ship even if it's not listed that way. Eg. if A is your home ship, and you modify B, then B will show up on the landing platform and A will disappear -- even if the 'ships' page still shows A as the home ship. This is likely a bug though, and very annoying.